# php-pdo-mysql-version-minimum v1 (detected: OFF)

Tags: magento2

I'm installing a new version of magento 2x my issue is that I'm getting this error:

> php-pdo-mysql-version-minimum v1 (detected: OFF)

on install, I'm using php7.0 and i checked PDO and it's on, any idea what else is causing this?